# Error inserting in hive table with mapreduce error

Tags: hadoop, hive

I've just set up hadoop 3.1.0 and hive 2.3.1 locally and I'm trying to insert into a test table. It keeps failing and I'm unsure why. Searching around the internet doesn't seem to help as I've tried everything.

Has anyone else had this sort of error before?

Full error:

```
hive> insert into gavtemp.staff values (1, 'bob', 111);
WARNING: Hive-on-MR is deprecated in Hive 2 and may not be available in the future versions. Consider using a different execution engine (i.e. spark, tez) or using Hive 1.X releases.
Query ID = gautamnewalkar_20180602170521_38a2fcf5-4cbd-4d84-aa52-f0385e9d798d
Total jobs = 3
Launching Job 1 out of 3
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
Starting Job = job_1527972955789_0008, Tracking URL = http://gautams-air.fios-router.home:8088/proxy/application_1527972955789_0008/
Kill Command = /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1527972955789_0008
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 0; number of reducers: 0
2018-06-02 17:05:43,494 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
Ended Job = job_1527972955789_0008 with errors
Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched:
Stage-Stage-1:  HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
hive>
```

Comment: The real error is within `Tracking URL =`

Comment: Please [edit] your question rather than post an answer with the errors

Comment: Sorry but I've given up. I've spent hours and it's just not worth it. I'm now just using docker to spin up an instance of hadoop/hive/tez so that I can just move on.

Comment: You might want to look into the Hortonworks Sandbox on Cloudera QuickStart VMs